# Index by date ranges in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I am new to using python pandas, and have the below script to pull in time series data from an excel file, set the dates = index, and then will want to perform various calculations on the data referencing by date. Script:

```
df  = pd.read_excel("myfile.xls")
df = df.set_index(df.Date)
df = df.drop("Date",1)
df.index.name = None
df.head()
```

The output of that (to give you a sense of the data) is:

```
              Px1      Px2     Px3   Px4     Px5       Px6         Px7    
2015-08-12  19.850000  10.25  7.88  10.90  109.349998  106.650002  208.830002
2015-08-11  19.549999  10.16  7.81  10.88  109.419998  106.690002  208.660004
2015-08-10  19.260000  10.07  7.73  10.79  109.059998  105.989998  210.630005
2015-08-07  19.240000  10.08  7.69  10.92  109.199997  106.430000  207.919998
2015-08-06  19.250000  10.09  7.76  10.96  109.010002  106.010002  208.350006
```

When I try to retrieve data based on one date like  `df.loc['20150806']` that works, but when I try to retrieve a slice like `df.loc['20150806':'20150812']` I return `Empty DataFrame`.

Again, the index is a DateTimeIndex with dtype = 'datetime64[ns]', length = 1412, freq = None, tz = None

Like I said, my ultimate goal is to be able to group the data by Day, Month, Year, different periods etc., and perform calculations on the data. I want to give that context, but don't even want to get into that here since I'm clearly stuck on something more basic - perhaps misunderstanding how to operate with a DateTimeIndex

Thank you.

EDIT: Meant to also include, I think the main problem I referenced with indexing has something to do with freq=0, bc when I tried simpler examples with contiguous date series, I did not have this problem.

Comment: Your index is not sorted, or at least it is decreasing instead of increasing. That's why the slicing returns an empty dataframe (the 12th august is before the 6th august in the frame)

Comment: Try `df = df.sort_index()` and then try to slice again.

Comment: Expanding on what @joris is suggesting, you could also slice by reversing the order in one of two ways: `df.loc['2015-08-12':'2015-08-10']` or `df.loc['2015-08-10':'2015-08-12':-1]` But without an explicit sort (a good suggestion of course), it's not necessarily implied that the results of the slice will be sorted either. You're effectively doing an `iloc` style slice.

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc['2015-08-12':'2015-08-10']` and `df.loc['2015-08-10':'2015-08-12':-1]` both work. `df = df.sort_index()` and slicing the way I was trying also works. Thank you all. Was missing the forest for the trees there I think.